# Execute regex located in an external file in python

Tags: python, regex

I need to load from an external file some regular expressions that must be executed...

The algorithm doesn't need to know what kind of regex they are... but at the end it must print the label

```
    email_re=["EMAIL","([^@|\s]+@[^@]+\.[^@|\s]+)"];
    phone_re=["PHONE","(\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}|\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}|\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4})"];

    regexs=[email_re,
            phone_re]

    for regex in regexs:
        #print regex
        match = re.search(regex[1], prodotto)
        if match:
            print regex[0]+": "+match.group()
```

What is the best way to create the regexs array defining all the regex in an external text files ?

Comment: do the program need to know if the regex is a email regex or phone regex, etc?

Comment: It must print the label of the regex that is executing

Comment: you can put a json in a file and load it in the program.
{"email" : "email regex here", ...}

Comment: In this way the algorithm must know the key...?

Comment: if the external file can by a python file, just create the list or a dictionary and import it. If the file have to be a human readable/writable text file you could use a json file format

Comment: that's a good option too. Just create a python file with a dictionary {label: regex, ...} and import it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using json as external file, try this:

```
import json

json_data=open('regex.json')
data = json.load(json_data)

for label, regex in data.items():
    print label
    print regex # process your regex here instead print
```

json file:

```
{
 "email" : "([^@|\\s]+@[^@]+\\.[^@|\\s]+)",
 "phone" : "(\\d{3}[-\\.\\s]??\\d{3}[-\\.\\s]??\\d{4}|\\(\\d{3}\\)\\s*\\d{3}[-\\.\\s]??\\d{4}|\\d{3}[-\\.\\s]??\\d{4})"
}
```